# Error al visualizar el modelo 3D en AR js

Tags: html, realidad-aumentada, ar.js

estoy intentando hacer que un codigo QR pueda salir un modelo 3d y redes sociales para una web, estilo tarjeta de visita interactiva, estoy usando AR.js y aframe pero al visualizar el codigo QR a veces aparece y desaparece y no se visualiza en ninguna posicion sale aleatorio dentro del codigo QR, si alguien me puede ayudar o si hay otra biblioteca js de AR que sea mas adecuada para codigos QR.

El codigo es este:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <a-scene arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; trackingMethod: best;" renderer="antialias: true;">
    <a-box position="0 0.5 0" material="opacity:0.5;"></a-box>
    <!-- Carga del modelo GLTF -->
    <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="modelo-gltf" src="marker.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <!-- Código QR que activa el modelo -->
    <a-marker type="pattern" url="marker.patt">
      <!--<a-entity position="0 0.3 0">-->
      <a-gltf-model src="#modelo-gltf" scale="2 2 2" position="0 1 0" animation-mixer class="clickable" event-set__click="_event: click; scale: 1.5 1.5 1.5;">
      </a-gltf-model>
      <!-- </a-entity>-->
      <a-image src="facebook.png" position="0 -0.3 0" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5" link="href: https://www.facebook.com/tu_usuario; title: Facebook; visualAspectEnabled: false;">
      </a-image>

    </a-marker>

    <a-entity camera look-controls></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```